# Confused about Finite fields and polynomials

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I'm asked to give a polynomial that has a root over a finite field but not a root over R. My understanding is that the finite field is contained in R (more restrictive) so how can there be a root in one but not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finite fields have a characteristic which is not 0,  which creates other things.   For example, consider $f(x)=x^2+1$.   Clearly in $\mathbb R$,  this has no roots.  But if you are in the field of 2 elements,  then 1 is a root, as $1+1=0$

Comment: Does that mean for a root to exist, it has to be within the elements of the field? i.e. Would something like $$x^3+2$$ not have a root in the field of 7 elements, but it would have a root over the reals?

Comment: Yes , we only talk about roots existing if its an element of the field.   Otherwise the roots exist in field extensions, but not the field itself

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $\mathbb R$, then no finite fields aren't contained in $\mathbb R$. To see this, note that finite fields have characteristic $p$ for some prime $p$, i.e. $p=0$. However this is certainly not true over the real numbers, which have characteristic $0$.

Like Alan said, $x^2+1$ has no roots over $\mathbb R$, but does have roots over the field with $p$ elements whenever $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.